# Stutters and lags after updating

Tags: 18.04, updates, amd-graphics

I recently got an SSD for my desktop PC and wanted to install Ubuntu on it.

To begin with everything seemed okay and there were no lags. However, after I accepted the recommended updates in Software Updater or use `sudo apt upgrade`, I get severe micro-stutters and lags which makes the operative system not worth using.

I have tried to reinstall Ubuntu on my SSD five times now and the problems always happen after I update. I managed to narrow the problematic update to just 9 sub-updates within "Ubuntu base" by downloading just a few updates at a time until the problem occurred. The update that causes this problem seems to be the same update that lets the OS detect which monitors I'm using and allow me to use my second monitor.

My system specs are:

- AMD RX 5700,
- AMD Ryzen 3600,
- MSI Mortar B450,
- Crucial BX500 SSD,
- Vengeance 16GB 3000MHz,

I'm using Ubuntu LTS 18.04 with the 5.3.0-28-generic kernel and GNOME 3.28.2.

I have none of these problems on my laptop with garbage specs, so I don't understand why it is a problem on my relatively good desktop PC. I appreciate any help I can get with this problem.

> [One of these updates caused this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T6C4.png)

Edit:
Results from `free -h`:

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        15G        1,6G         13G        213M        1,1G         13G
Swap:      2,0G          0B        2,0G
```

I set my swap size to be 20GB in the other OS installations, but decided to just go with the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option for my latest install and it automatically made it 2GB.

Edit2:
Only the RAM is overclocked (to 3000MHz), and I'm using the newest BIOS version available. There is usually 0 B/s being written and read while the error happens.

Edit3:
[image: Gnome extensions installed]
Edit4:

What I could gather from logs:

- [journalctl errors](https://pastebin.com/tR60CE3t)
- [amdgpu warning](https://pastebin.com/62HNMq1x)
- [ICC_PROFILE denied](https://pastebin.com/Bk4j6XJP)

The amdgpu warning seems to happen a lot, often multiple times within a second. Some of the times it is followed by the ICC_PROFILE thing.

Edit5:
When I try to install gpu drivers through AMD's website, I get this error: `Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-28-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/19.50-967956/build/make.log for more information.`
 and this warning at the end of the installation: `WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel`

[make.log](https://pastebin.com/u4TgreVv)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`, and use `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to get your BIOS version, and then go to the motherboard manufacturer's web site and check for a newer BIOS. Report back.

Comment: Your BIOS should be version 7B89v1D, released Jan 7, 2020.

Comment: I've now updated the BIOS, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Good job on the BIOS update. At least we can say that it's out of the picture. Can you create a Ubuntu Live 19.10 DVD/USB on a flash drive, boot to it, and see if you see the same problem?

Comment: CPU and RAM are not overclocked, correct?

Comment: Install IOTOP and see if something is running the disk. Check for firmware updates for the SSD. Temporarily try this... `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10` and see if it makes any difference (60 is the default).

Comment: I made a bootable USB for 19.10, but I couldn't get it to download the updates that caused this problem without properly installing the OS to a disk first, due to it being read-only or something. The only overclocked part in my PC is the RAM. There is very little read and write going on, both are usually at 0.00B/s while the problem happens.

Comment: I also didn't notice any differences after setting swappiness to 10

Comment: I'm just checking a number of common problem areas... as we don't have much to go on. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, and temporarily down-clock your RAM to standard freq. I guess that's XMP? Report back.

Comment: Turns out the BIOS update removed the RAM overclock, so that wasn't an issue. When I try to run that command, I just get a "No such file or directory" error

Comment: Tell me what you see at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

Comment: I installed the Firefox extension, but it doesn't seem to work. https://imgur.com/a/VvISsjj

Comment: Click on the documentation link and install the connector. Then it'll work.

Comment: Got it to work. It only shows two extensions; AppIndicators and Dock.

Comment: That's great! Now, for lack of more data, let's try this simple test. If you don't have another user account on this system, temporarily create a new account called "Testing", or whatever. Log into this new account, and see if the problem still occurs. Report back.

Comment: Everything felt a lot smoother on the other user, but the problem was still there.

Comment: Good job on the account test. We still don't have enough data. Review the various logs to see if you can identify what might be going wrong. `more /var/log/syslog`, `dmesg`, and `journalctl`. Use the man pages if required.

Comment: I feel I'm in a little over my head here, but I copied what I assumed to be relevant from the logs

Comment: Good job! Do you know what version AMD driver you have? Do `dpkg -l *amd*`, it should be version 19.50 from 12/19/2019, else go to https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-5700-series/amd-radeon-rx-5700-series/amd-radeon-rx-5700 and get the new version. Report back.

Comment: You also have gnome-shell issues  (`ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`) and a possible dkms issue (`dkms status`). Report back.

Comment: When I try to install those drivers I get an error and a warning. dkms status says I'm using version 19.50

Comment: Yes, the dkms driver failed to build properly. It's probably because you've got the newer kernel 5.3.0-28. Edit your question and show me `dkms status`. We'll uninstall it and see if there's an alternate driver via `Software & Updates`.

Comment: Did you install the "Open" or "Pro" AMD drivers?

Comment: To uninstall AMD, do `amdgpu-uninstall` or `amdgpu-pro-uninstall`. `dkms status` should then NOT show amdgpu*. Contact AMD and tell them that their AMDGPU 19.50 dkms drivers won't build on kernel 5.3.0-28.

Comment: Rolling the kernel back to 5.0.0-23-generic solved this for me. I'm still unable to get it to work on the 5.3.0-28 kernel, but I guess AMD will fix that eventually

Comment: Don't assume that AMD will fix your problem, unless you talk to their support folks about your specific experience, and that 19.50 won't build with kernel 5.3.0-28.

Comment: I did tell the guy on AMD Tech Support, but he didn't really seem to care. I don't know what else I can do

Comment: Ask to escalate the trouble report.